# How to get the actual size of transformed CALayer?

Tags: core-animation, calayer, catransform3d

I have a `200x200 pixel` `CALayer` instance to which I've applied two transformations:

- scaled down to 50%
- applied a 3D perspective

Now I want to align the transformed layer with another layer. To do that I need the size (width and height) of the transformed layer.

The problem is that `layer.bounds` still returns `200x200` for the layer, but because of the perspective transformation the actual visible width is less and the height more than `200`. The bounds of the presentation layer return `0`, by the way.

Is there any way how I can determine the exact size of a transformed `CALayer` exactly as it is drawn on screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally figured it out: the `bounds` remain unchanged when applying a transformation, but what changes is the layer's `frame` property.

Solution is to use `layer.frame.size` instead of `layer.bounds.size`.

This is mentioned in the Core Animation Programming Guide:

> Layers have an implicit frame that is a function of the position, bounds, anchorPoint, and transform properties.